# Are operations equal if there exists isomorphism between abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is a set and $\circ, * $ are operations such that $(G,\circ), (G,*)$ are abelian groups, which are isomorphic. Do there assumptions imply that operations $\circ, *$ are equal or there exists an example, in which they are not?

Edit. I forgot to mention that these groups have the same identity element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples where they aren't. For a simple one, consider the abelian group on the set $\{0,1\}$ with $1 \circ 1 = 0 \circ 0 = 1$, and $1 \circ 0 = 0$. This is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

In general, you can get examples of what you're looking for by swapping around the roles of elements of $G$ (as above, where we made $1$ into the identity element and $0$ into the non-identity element).

If you want the groups to have the same identity element, you could take the cyclic group of order $4$ (with underlying set $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$) and, say, swap the roles of $2$ and $3$.

That is, these two abelian groups:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}$$
and
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\circ & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\ 
3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}$$
have the same underlying set and the same identity, and are isomorphic, but have different operations (for example, $3+3=2$, but $3 \circ 3 = 0$).

Comment: But the groups which are isomorphic are supposed to be the same set. In your example there are two different sets $\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
It's obvious that if you take two different sets the operations won't be equal.

Comment: The underlying set of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is $\{0,1\}$. Or at least that's the way I'm used to defining it. If you'd rather think of it as having some other underlying set, just replace the $0$ and the $1$ in my example with the two elements of that...

Comment: See my update for an example where the identity element stays the same.

Comment: The underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{2\mathbb{Z},2\mathbb{Z}+1\}$ i.e the cosets of a subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}=\{k\in\mathbb{Z}: 2|k\}$.

Comment: But your second example is something I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, pretend my first example was the group on that set with $(2\Bbb{Z}+1)\circ(2\Bbb{Z}+1)=(2\Bbb{Z})\circ(2\Bbb{Z})=2\Bbb{Z}+1$, $(2\Bbb{Z})\circ(2\Bbb{Z}+1)=2\Bbb{Z}$. The point is, the underlying set of a group doesn't really matter (except for its cardinality) until you specify an operation.

Comment: Ok. I see the point.